# Is distributed SQL Server with multiple read-write nodes possible?

Tags: sql-server

Do SQL Server Always-On availability groups allow multiple nodes that can be written to?

I have an application that's using SQL Server 2022. We currently use a single Azure SQL Server. We'd like to be able to horizontally scale our database. We looked into CockroachDB, but it uses Postgres syntax and also seems to be missing some major features we use (table valued parameters, fulltext index, declaring variables in queries, etc). Ideally, we'd just have a distributed SQL Server database.

Insight from people who've horizontally scaled SQL Server or migrated from SQL Server to a distributed db engine would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like it might be supported in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-introduction?view=azuresql. But I need to try it out.

Comment: Eh, sounds like that's just sharding data across multiple nodes. But what I'm after is replication with multi-node read _and_ writes.

Comment: Reading that link, it's just sharding, but fancy. You can do that irrespective of AGs or Azure. I helped implement sharding on MSSQL at my last job. The way we chose to do it was to have an entity → shard lookup table that the app would query (and cache aggressively as that relationship was immutable) and all the data for that entity was contained in that shard database.

Comment: I want to avoid sharding--sounds like it can be brittle and a maintenance headache. Amazon's babelfish sounds pretty promising. It currently doesn't support MERGE or Full-text search, but it's open source. Sounds like MariaDB supports some sql server syntax too.

Comment: If you're willing to totally change your persistence layer (which considering babelfish/MariaDB suggests that you are), the world's your oyster. But at that point, your question of "how to do that in MSSQL" is no longer relevant.

Comment: The largest part of this project would be converting our schema and dapper queries to work with the new persistence layer. So if that can be minimized by MSSQL syntax being supported, that'd be great. Migrating data wouldn't be terribly complicated, I don't think. But before deciding to do that, I wanted to determine if Azure SQL or SQL itself could be  distributed and could have multiple read+write nodes scattered across earth, so we could just turn that on.

Comment: Or if there are plans to do such a thing. But it looks like the closest to that currently would be using babelfish with an underlying distributed database. So that _might_ somewhat unfortunately be the answer to my question.